# Why my code is giving this error "TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable"?

Tags: python, indexing, typeerror

I want to take an input of two digits from user and then add them by using indexing. But my code shows error.What is the problem with my code and please explain it in easy words.

I typed the following code.

```
nmbr_1=int(input("Enter a two digit number: "))

a= (nmbr_1[0])

b= (nmbr_1[1])

print(a+b)
```

It showed "TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable"

Comment: This error is raised because `nmbr_1` is an `int` and `int`s aren't subscriptable, just like the error indicates. Do you think that `nmbr_1` is a `list`? If you expect `nmbr_1` to be a `list`, you'll need to parse it as such rather than casting to `int`.

Comment: The error is telling you that you can't use the subscript operator (`[]`) on an `int`.  Presumably you are trying to pull out the first and second digits - for that, you'll have to leave `nmbr_1` as a `str`, then convert the digits to `int`s before adding them.

Answer (score 1):

This will parse the input as a list of two, single-digit integers.

```py
nmbr_1=[int(x) for x in input("Enter a two digit number: ")]

a = nmbr_1[0]

b = nmbr_1[1]

print(a+b)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python, you can't simply access the digits of a number using `[]`. Instead try this:

```py
nmbr_1 = input("Enter a two digit number: ")

a = int(nmbr_1[0])
b = int(nmbr_1[1])

print(a + b)
```

Since `input()` returns a `str` value, you can use the `[]` to get the different characters in the string. Here I split the number up into its digits before converting them to `int`s.

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

That's because the input is in the form of an integer using something like `num_arr = [int(i) for i in str(nmbr_1)]`. You might have to split it into an array before calling `num_arr[0]` and `num_arr[1]`.